# Random value in an given ARRAY?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have written the below code to find a random value in an array.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 1) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='GXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

$numbers_rev = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","."); 
$letter_rev = array("A","L","B","E","R","T","O","I","N",generateRandomString(),"/");    

$phrase_rev = "5000";

echo $rev = str_replace($numbers_rev,$letter_rev,$phrase_rev);
```

It gives an output as: `RXXX` or `RZZZ` or `RYYY` or `RGGG`

I am expecting the output: `RZGXZ`

Help please, thanks

Comment: The generate random function is only called in the creation of the `$letter_rev` array - so the swap for 0 is set once as `X,Y,G,Z`. If you want set net random each time I would suggest for-loop with map for the conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$phrase_rev="5000";

$str_ctr=strlen($phrase_rev);
$arr1 = str_split($phrase_rev);

for($ctr=0;$ctr<$str_ctr;$ctr++){   

    $shuffled=substr(str_shuffle('XYZG'),0,1);
    $aa=$arr1[$ctr];
    $numbers_revs=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","."); 
    $letter_revs=array("A","L","B","E","R","T","O","I","N",$shuffled,"/");
    echo $revs = str_replace($numbers_revs,$letter_revs,$aa);
}
```

Output is now random but char repeats... Hope someone can improve this. Thanks